# c# validation all text box that start with the same name

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, numbers

I have windows application in c#

with a form with 7 text box that i want to check (and more controls in the form)

i want to check all this 7 text box , that the user enter in data , and this is a number

all this text box **start** with the **same name**

How can i do it ?

thanks.

i start to write something like that but i am stack

```
     foreach (TextBox box in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
.Where(tb => tb.Text.StartsWith('tbwin')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (TextBox box in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
       .Where(tb => tb.Name.StartsWith("tbwin")))
{
    int result;
    if(!int.TryParse(box.Text, out result))
    {
         //Not OK. Inform user
         MessageBox.Show("You need to write a valid number in " + box.Name);
    } 
}
```

Comment: its on : tb.Name.StartsWith('tbwin')

Comment: agument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Comment: @Haim, sorry, just noticed the single quotes. Have changed it to a proper string using double quotes.

Comment: now i dont have error, but not work if i dont enter any thing in text box , i try to figure why

Comment: I've added an error message to the code. Is that not what you want? Should it be ok if the user leaves the textbox empty?

Comment: its not catch the controls , something in the statement dont work its empty and do not loop

Comment: Oh, ok. Are you sure the casing of "tbwin" is correct? Maybe the names are actually "tbWin" or something like that?

Comment: when i debug the box variable empty

Comment: Ok, when debugging, do you see the textboxes in the `this.Controls` collection? Maybe they have been added to some child control.

Comment: no i  see this  , they under this , this.controls seem to be empty, its related to that my form in tab?

Comment: Yes, for the above code to work, it must be in the form/control that actually contains those textboxes.

Comment: they are be in the same tab with button , when the user click its come to function to validate

Answer (score 2):

You could just make them all a `MaskedTextBox` and make sure they put in numbers that way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx